# Using parameters in Flask url

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to put *PATH* like this `text/text.txt` into URL parameter in Flask ?
It is important that it contains *PATH* with slash and dot.

```
@app.route('/<path>')
def getPath(path):
    return path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) with the prefix `path` your requirements should be met.

```py
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def getPath(filename):
    return filename
```